# Firebase hosting : unable to verify first certificate

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Is anybody here to help me with this ?
Whenever I try to initiate firebase hosting, I get this error.
Error is "Server Error. unable to verify the first certificate".
Two months passed but I haven't got the solution. Even I contacted Firebase Support Team, but they didn't help.
Please, help me.

**Firebase-debug.log :**

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  F:\cv_web\build

[info] 

=== Project Setup


[info] 

[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.

[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 

[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.

[info] 

[debug] [2019-12-04T21:11:12.162Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100  


[debug] [2019-12-04T21:11:13.569Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200

[info] i  Using project abhijeetbharti-b42e1 (abhijeetbharti)

[info] 

=== Hosting Setup

[info] 

[info] Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that

[info] will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you

[info] have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

[info] 

[info] +  Wrote build/404.html

[debug] [2019-12-04T21:11:25.792Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json  

[debug] [2019-12-04T21:11:27.490Z] Error: unable to verify the first certificate

at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)

at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)

at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:478:20)

at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)

at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12)

[error] 

[error] Error: Server Error. unable to verify the first certificate
```

Comment: Do you include certificate bundle see: [Unable to verify the first certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35274353/2150063)

Comment: how to do that ? please provide clarification. @hal9256